# Google map markers will randomly not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

My code for this instance of map markers will execute correctly about 60% of the time, but the other 40% the map markers won't show up...although they will drop if you interact with the map, such as dragging it. Has anyone ever had this problem before? I have arrays of values that have the coordinates and it just seems weird that it only works some of the time.

```
 var i = 0;

 for (item in t) {
     var m = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: google_map,
     icon: map_marker[i],
     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
     title: t[i],
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(x[i], y[i]),
     html: h[i]
    });

  i++;

}
```

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle or a link to a map that exhibits the problem?

Comment: My guess is that some of your arrays doesn't have values at some indexes (check what are the values that you use during creation of the markers). Anyway, instead of keeping information in five different arrays you should have them in one array of structures. In my opinion you shouldn't also mix iterating "for (item in t)" with accessing by manually generated index